# 'Request.RequestURI can't be set in client request' error when resend it through proxy

Tags: go, http-proxy

When I try to resend requests from simple `proxy`

```
http.HandleFunc("/",func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("proxy rq: %v", r)
    client := &http.Client{}
    proxyRes, err := client.Do(r) //   Get "http://localhost:8097/tmp": http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err proxy request: %v",err)
    }
    resBody := proxyRes.Body
    defer resBody.Close()
    if _, err := io.Copy(w, resBody); err != nil {
        log.Printf("copy error:%v\n", err)
    }
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8099", nil)
```

, with set `http_proxy` ENV (to send requests thought my proxy)

```
% export http_proxy=http://localhost:8099 
% curl -v http://localhost:8097/tmp
```

I get an `error` like

```
Get "http://localhost:8097/tmp": http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the client request as a parameter of `Do`. Create a new request with the same parameter as `r`, then perform `Do` on this request

Answer (score 1):

The error is defined in the `../src/net/http/client.go:217` (https://go.dev/src/net/http/client.go) as:

```golang
if req.RequestURI != "" {
    req.closeBody()
    return nil, alwaysFalse, errors.New("http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests")
}
```

You should be able to reuse existing `r *http.Request` if you set `r.RequestURI = ""` before sending a HTTP request:

```golang
r.RequestURI = ""
proxyRes, err := client.Do(r)
```

Comment: You'd _think_ this would work, but it doesn't unfortunately.